# Recommened way to use flyway with travis

Tags: travis-ci, flyway

I want to use flyway on travis as part of the build. For that I need to have flyway's code on travis to allow me to run it.
I can run a scrip that downloads flyway, extracts it and runs it but that seems wasteful and I also don't see a canonical link for downloading flyway that I can rely on.
Did anyone do this?

Answer (score 1):

The approach you describe is the correct one. This can optionally be combined with Travis' support for caching if deemed beneficial in your case.